# Good source of information about VxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

I'm new to the VxWorks Environment are there any good sources of information out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your budget allows it, I would recommend taking one of the courses offered by WindRiver.  My company brought in one of their trainers to teach a class on-site and it was excellent.  They provided hands-on programming activities and a lot of information.  If you are new to the concepts of real-time or embedded programming, they provided the necessary background information, and even if you were already familiar with these (as I was), there was plenty of useful training specific to VxWorks and Workbench.  I believe they also organize their own courses, in addition to coming to companies.  [Course Schedule](http://education.windriver.com/lmt/CLMSCATALOGSCHEDULE.prMain?in_sessionId=&in_portId=0&in_folderName=North%20America)

Comment: agreed; the vxworks way is sometimes a bit different to what you're used (depending where you come from). The courses give a lot of info so you'll know where to look when you encounter a problem. Depending on the number of developers you can consider to customize a training. I've done that and was happy with the result. This way you can fast-forward through the been-there-done-that parts.

Answer (score 5):

2 Books helped me:

- Real-Time Concepts for Embedded Systems ISBN-10: 1578201241 ISBN-13: 978-1578201242
  (Basic RT concepts, Common Patterns)
- Tornado and VxWorks: What's not in the Manual ISBN-10: 3833410698 ISBN-13: 978-3833410697